# Clang-format: How do you avoid a line break before try in a function-try-block?

Tags: c++, try-catch, clang-format

For example, the current code:

```
void foo() try
{
    // stuff..
}
catch(...)
{
    // stuff..
}
```

will always be modified by my clang-format settings into:

```
void foo()
try
{
    // stuff..
}
catch (...)
{
    // stuff..
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

My clang-format settings: [.clang-format](https://gist.github.com/theroyn/c24295cf2c61511b66358c162f8df652)